# how to implement a cronjob completely?i want to know step by step procedures

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cron-task

i want to implement a cronjob.
this is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
try {
  $dbh = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'portugal')
        or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
  $selected = mysql_select_db("AppUsers",$dbh)
        or die("Could not select examples");
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }



$dbh->query("UPDATE conditions
                            SET status='F' 
                            WHERE
                            category='b'");
```

its location is `/var/www/laravel_app/public/check.php`

i make a cronjob by typing the command `crontab -e`. and i pasted this code at the end and saved it.`45 13 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/laravel_app/public/check.php`
but there is no change in my table after this time.help.tysm  in advance

Answer (score 0):

this is how i do it in my backup server

> 0 7 * * 1-5 wget --quiet -O /dev/null "http://10.29.110.10/files/sync_check.php"